# Get percentage of files copied from a list

Tags: vb.net, progress-bar

I have an app that copies files in a list to a new directory. I'm trying to get the progress bar to work but my formula results with a System.OverflowException: Arithmetic operation resulted in an over flow. I've looked at other examples using file copying but they are centered on using the source folder divided by destination folder. Mines a little bit different because I'm using files in a list.

Thank you for the help.

Code

```
        Dim progress = fileCount * 100 / fileList.Count()
        BackgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(progress)
```

Code for getting file Count

```
Dim FILE_NAME As String

    FILE_NAME = txtFileName.Text
    Dim fileNames = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(FILE_NAME)

    fCount = 0
    For i = 0 To fileNames.Count() - 1
        Dim fileName = fileNames(i)
        sFileToFind = location & "\" & fileName & "*.*"
        Dim paths = IO.Directory.GetFiles(location, fileName, IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories)
        If Not paths.Any() Then
            System.IO.File.AppendAllText(orphanedFiles, fileName & vbNewLine)
        Else
            For Each pathAndFileName As String In paths
                If System.IO.File.Exists(pathAndFileName) = True Then
                    sRegLast = pathAndFileName.Substring(pathAndFileName.LastIndexOf("\") + 1)
                    Dim toFileLoc = System.IO.Path.Combine(createXMLFldr, sRegLast)
                    Dim moveToFolder = System.IO.Path.Combine(MoveLocation, "XML files", sRegLast)

                    'if toFileLoc = XML file exists move it into the XML files folder
                    If System.IO.File.Exists(toFileLoc) = False Then
                        System.IO.File.Copy(pathAndFileName, moveToFolder)
                        System.IO.File.AppendAllText(ListofFiles, sRegLast & vbNewLine)
                        fCount = fCount + 1

                        XMLFilename = (sRegLast) + vbCrLf
                    End If
                End If
            Next
        End If

        Dim srcCount = paths.Count()
        If (paths.Count() = 0) Then
            srcCount = 1
        End If


        Dim progress = CType(fCount * 100 / srcCount, Integer)
        BackgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(progress)


    Next
```

Comment: You need to check if `fileList.Count = 0` to assure you are not dividing by 0.

Comment: @dashier I added an if statement that changes the fileList.Count if it's zero make it one. But I still get the OverflowException

Comment: You need to show a minimum amount of code to reproduce the problem. _Not_ your _whole_ program, but enough that we can see how `fileList` is created/populated. What happens if you use a debugger and look at the values? Also, what is the type required by `BackgroundWorker1.ReportProgress()`?

Comment: How do you count the filecount?

Comment: I have a text file with the list of files. I read all lines into a fileList

Comment: @daShier I've added the code I use for the fileCount list.

Comment: Explicitly state the type during a conversion. Try using `Dim progress As Long = fileCount * 100 / fileList.Count()`

Comment: @preciousbetine I recieved the same ArgumentOutOfRangeException

Comment: @MaxineHammett are you just wanting the difference between what files are left to copy to the source folder and what is already in the source folder?

Comment: What is the value of progress when the exception is thrown? If needed set a breakpoint and test it.  Also force the value to >=1 and <=100 with something like progress = Math.Max(Math.Min(progress,99),1) to prevent the exception until you resolve what the calculation should be.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ problem I'm getting is on progressbar.value = e.progress exceeds 100 it throws the exception error. Having the file left to copy in source folder needs to be from the list of files list.

Comment: @JonRoberts the value was 200 when I ran it..

Comment: @JonRoberts using the Math.Max simulates what I want to happen. But what I really want is a percentage copy of all the items in filelist. So if I have 1040 files to copy i want that to be the Max value and the min value to be fcount.

Comment: paths.Count() always give the last iteration, so fcount may be can be more greater than paths.Count(), so progress will be more than 100%, I think

Comment: I Suppose, that line Dim progress = CType(fCount * 100 / srcCount, Integer) can be change with Dim progress = CType(fCount * 100 / fileNames.count , Integer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This for BackGroundWorker, I hope will this can resolve the trouble of the next call to update progress bar:

```
'This button1_click event to begin or stop async of backGrounedWorker
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    BackgroundWorker1.WorkerReportsProgress = True
    BackgroundWorker1.WorkerSupportsCancellation = True
    BackgroundWorker1.CancelAsync()
    Try
        BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
End Sub

'Here your backGroundProcess
Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
    Dim FILE_NAME As String

    FILE_NAME = txtFileName.Text 'can be changed
    Dim fileNames = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(FILE_NAME)

    Dim Location As String = "C:\MyData\Folder1" 'can be changed
    Dim moveToFolder As String = "C:\MyData\Folder2" 'can be changed
    Dim fCount As Integer = 0
    For Each fileName In fileNames

        Dim paths = IO.Directory.GetFiles(Location, fileName,
                                          IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories)

        If paths.Count > 0 Then
            Try
                System.IO.File.Copy(paths(0), moveToFolder & "\" & fileName, True)
            Catch ex As Exception
                Debug.Print(ex.Message)
            End Try
        End If
        For a = 1 To 100
            Debug.Print(a.ToString)
        Next

        'If any request pending process will be stop (when Button1_click happen while process running (BackGroundWorker in Action))
        If BackgroundWorker1.CancellationPending = True Then Exit For

        fCount += 1
        Dim Progress As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(fCount * 100 / fileNames.Count)
        BackgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(progress)
    Next
End Sub

'This will show you the progress in your progress bar
Private Sub bw1_ProgressChanged(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.ProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged
    Me.ProgressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage
End Sub

'Your Process Have Been Complete Here
Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted
    MessageBox.Show("Finish")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

This last modification from me:

```
    ListBox1.Items.Clear()
    Dim FILE_NAME As String

    FILE_NAME = "c:\YourFolder\YourFile.txt" 'can be changed
    Dim fileNames = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(FILE_NAME)

    For Each MyFile In fileNames
        ListBox1.Items.Add(MyFile)
    Next

    Dim Location As String = "C:\YourFolder1" 'can be changed
    Dim moveToFolder As String = "C:\YourFolder2" 'can be changed
    Dim fCount As Integer = 0
    For Each fileName In fileNames

        Dim paths = IO.Directory.GetFiles(Location, fileName,
                                          IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories)

        If paths.Count > 0 Then
            Try
                System.IO.File.Copy(paths(0), fileName)
            Catch ex As Exception
            End Try
        End If
        fCount += 1
        Dim progress As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(fCount * 100 / fileNames.Count)
    Next
```

Comment: @answered This worked great until the i call the progress bar a second time with  progress = Convert.ToInt32(iCount * 100 / ListDedupedGraphics.Count). It only goes to 49% then saids the files copied is complete

Comment: For 100% result wheter the file you search can be found or can not be found, you must  change marked fCount += 1 under else statement to be unmarked. And about The progress bar, I think it can be refreshed, for example myprogressbar.refresh. For the more better you put progress calculation line and progressbar action before exit from for loop.

Comment: I just modify your coding with some comments that I added

Comment: And additionally, may be you can count how many files that can't be found.

Comment: how would I resolve the progress bar only going to 49%?

Comment: Have you counted how many files found are? And how many files you searched?

Comment: yes I have. iCount * 10/ ListDedupedGraphics.count(). It only goes to 49% then saids it's complete

Comment: I have edited the coding to be able showing you (in Listbox2) which file that can't be found...

Comment: Thank you for the code editing. I'm having trouble with a second call to update the progress bar. It only goes to 49% then saids it's complete. I'm using the code progress = Convert.ToInt32(iCount * 100 / ListDedupedGraphics.Count)

Comment: I have edited again as the last, I hope this will give you 100% as your hope. And I don't have any idea about your second call to update the progress bar, because I don't understand your progress bar,